# What is the size limit for upload and download from the Autodesk Forge Object Storage Service

Tags: object, service, storage, revit, autodesk-data-management

I am using Authentication V1 and I am wanting to use the OSS to store a .rvt or a .rfa file. What are the size limits, transfer rate limits for uploading and downloading. These could be approximate values. I am just weighing my options between Drop Box and the Forge for collaboration and showing clients a web browser with the ability to let them rotate and view a model externally.

Comment: oh btw, if i have to with drop box it wont be because i think i can spin a model in the air, it would be due to the server limitations with forge if there are any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object size limit is set on s3 (that's our persistent storage), its limit is 5tb. There is no transfer rate limit set today, it will just depend on what the AWS instances or the Apigee API proxy provides and what's currently available for each client considering the usage at the moment.

Comment: thanx that answered my question